# Question about a Linear Algebra with exponential functions

Tags: linear-algebra

The Question: Let $f$, $g$ $ \in \mathbb{F}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ be the functions defined by $f(t) = e^{rt}$ and $g(t)= e^{st}$ where $ r \neq s. $
Prove that f and g are linearly independent in $\mathbb{F}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$.

My attempt: Let $\mathbb{F}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ be the vector space. Let $f$, $g$ $\in \mathbb{F}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$. Suppose by contradiction, that $f$ and $g$ are linearly dependent. That means if there exists scalars, $a$ and $b$ $\in$ $F$ such that $ae^{rt} + be^{st} = 0$, then not all scalars, $a$ and $b$, are zero. I have completed this by cases.

Case 1 is when 
$a = 0$. Since we know that s is non-zero, and the exponential function maps to $\mathbb{R} \mapsto (0,\infty)$,  this implies that $b= 0$ and which implies that $f,g$ would be linearly independent, which contradicts the statement that $f$ and $g$ are linearly dependent.

Case 2 is when $b =0$. This is similar to case 1, only except that we can prove that $a=0$ .

The third case is when both constants, $a$ and $b$, are non-zero. I have some sort of an idea but I am not sure if it is a valid one. I could factor out an $e^{st}$ to get $e^{st} (ae^{(r-s)t} +b) = 0$.  Since $s \neq 0$, and $e^{st} \neq 0$, this implies that $ae^{(r-s)t} +b = 0$.

This is all I got so far.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Looks great so far, keep going!  What you are saying is that, for every possible value of $t$, the function $ae^{(r-s)t} + b$ is equal to $0$, or in other words, $ae^{(r-s)t} = -b$.  So, an exponential function always equals a constant value.  What must be true in this situation?

Comment: Oh that happens when t is negative right?

Comment: Not necessarily.  Think about this:  If you have the equation $ae^{(r-s)t} = -b$, you could solve for $t$.  But this equation has to hold for every value of $t$.  How can that be?  (Hint: Overall, what are you trying to show here?)

Comment: Well the main idea is to show that one of the constants is zero. So from the equation, $e^{(r-s)t} =\frac{-b}{a} $, are we trying to show that either $t=0$, or that $r=s?$

Comment: Sure, you could deduce that $r=s$.  What would this imply about your initial assumptions?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $h(t) = af(t) + bg(t) = 0$, what is $h'(t)$?

Can you think of a way of using $h(t)$ and $h'(t)$ to prove that $r=s$?